# How to load mysql data on option html form

Tags: php, mysql

I have this option form:

```
<tr>
<td><font size="3">Civil Status</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
    <select name="cs" id="cs">
        <option>Single</option>
        <option>Married</option>
        <option>Widowed</option>

    </select></td></td>
```

What do I do in order to load it with mysql data, like this one:

```
<td width="23"><font size="3">Sex</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="174"><input name="sex" type="text"  maxlength="1" value="<?php echo $row["SEX"]; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not well formed, and we need the MySQL table layout, plus what information your reading from what table. Also, how do you want the form to be submitted? GET or POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query(blahblah);

<select name="cs" id="cs">
    <?php
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $line['id'] . '">' . $line['name'] . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Something like that should do it. If I understood the question correctly...